# Angular 6 conflict in router links on same root

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

**i have two routes :-**

**1- http://localhost:4200/members/10  ===> this for member's page**

**2- http://localhost:4200/members/10?tab=3  ===> this for chat page**

I want to make chat as a paid service so I create component I called it `charge` with this route ==> http://localhost:4200/charge  so if any member like to go to chat route he will be redirected to charge page as I create code in `ngOnInit` method in chat component like that

```
if(!this.authService.paid)
      {this.router.navigate(['charge']);}
```

When I go chat it redirects me to charge page and that's cool , the problem is that when I go member'page it redirects me to charge page and that's not cool at all, so please help me what can i do to solve this problem, thanks in advance

and this is my routes

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    {
        path: '',
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
        , canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'members', component: MemberListComponent, resolve: {
                    users: MemberListResolver
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'member/edit', component: MemberEditComponent, resolve: {
                    user: MemberEditResolver
                }, canDeactivate: [PreventUnsavedChangesGuard]
            },
            {
                path: 'members/:id', component: MemberDetailComponent, resolve: {
                    user: MemberDetailResolver
                }
            },

            {
                path: 'lists', component: ListsComponent, resolve: {
                    users: ListResolver
                }
            },
            { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent, resolve: { messages: MessageResolver }, canActivate: [MessagesGuard] },
            { path: 'charge', component: PaymentComponent }
        ]
    },

    { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Comment: please share your full code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use the same `ngOnInit` implementation for both pages '/member' and '/chat'. And if this `!this.authService.payed` returns `true`, you will always be redirected to '/charge' page.

But to have a better understanding, please provide your routing configuration.

**Edit:**

Thank you for adding your routes.

```
{
      path: 'members/:id', component: MemberDetailComponent, resolve: {
                user: MemberDetailResolver
      }
}
```

It seems like you check for `!this.authService.payed`  in MemberDetailComponent#ngOnInit, but you probably do not check your queryParam `?tab=3`.
To fix this issue quickly you can modify your if-condition:

```
if(!this.authService.payed && this.route.snapshot.queryParams['tab'] === 3)
```

where `this.route` has to be injected via constructor parameter

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)`

**But**
I think the best solution for this issue would be to add another child route for chat page and handle authorization with another 'canActivate'.

Comment: i add my routes now